# Make animation faster with animate

Tags: beamer, animate

I have a series of PNG figures that I use to make an animation in a `beamer` presentation. The animation works fine except that the frame rate is very slow, like 1 per second. I would like to make it faster, but how?

Answer (score 8):

It seems that the `{1}` just after the square bracket controls the frame rate:

```
\animategraphics[autoplay,loop,height=5cm]{1}{my_pngfiles_}{0}{22}
```

Changing that will change the speed apparently, e.g. to 8 say:

```
\animategraphics[autoplay,loop,height=5cm]{8}{my_pngfiles_}{0}{22}
```

Comment: The last parameter can be left blank `{}`.

Comment: @CodeMocker: The last one or two parameters can only be left blank if the animation frames are read from a multipage PDF.